# Getting data between components in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-cli

I really can't get binding data between components.

Steps,

1. get text value from `Child1` component
2. execute `Add` method on `App.vue`
3. send test value from `App.vue` and make a `v-for` list on `Child2`

No.3 is not working.
I dont' even know 1,2 are correct on code..
How can I get input data to show item list?

Here's my code: [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/parent-to-childbyclicking-et6yq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code fixed: https://codesandbox.io/s/parent-to-childbyclicking-pp4yy

You emit a `input` event on `Child1`, but the `App.vue` was not listening. Also, the list was wrongly pass on `Child2` props.

Feel free to comment if you don't understand any part ;)

Comment: thanks for your code.
I have a question for `:list="list"`

My understanding is like this:
`:aaa="bbb"`
`aaa` is same name as child component
`bbb` is for parent component to do method, and so on.
It's like `:callAddBtn="addBtn"`
Is not always like this?
`:list="list"` are the same. confusing..

Comment: These are props. In your example `:aaa:bbb`, this will 'link' the `aaa` property on the parent component to the `bbb` property on the child. Using this, when the `aaa` changes on the parent, those changes will occured on `bbb` on the child. Don't forget to declare this prop on the child component. More info & examples here : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Comment: ok, when `props`, `:ccc="ccc"` and add `props` on child component.
`:aaa="bbb"` is for when to make a action. I think I got it. Thank you very much.